# How to find system call implementations in Linux/Android 2.6.29?

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel

I want to modify some system calls for tracing purposes. To be specific, whenever a system call `open` is made, I want to print some messages.

I have been looking into the internet and the code and I found `open.c` in `kernel/goldfish/fs/` directory. And there are many functions  in this file. How would I know which function is being called exactly. I could have written some `printk` call in all these functions to find it but I have to do it for other system calls also.

So, I have a few questions,

1) What is the best way to find implementation details of system calls?

2) I am using Kernel 2.6.29 (goldfish-Android). Are system calls implementation different in different kernel versions?

3) `strace` tells me that `msgget` ,`msgrecv` and 'SYS_24' system calls are being made. I look into `Android/bionic/libc/SYSCALLS.txt` file and msgget is not there.

But when I look into `android/bionic/libc/kernel/arch-arm/asm/unistd.h` file, I can find `msgget` there. I can't understand what's going on and then how can I find implementation for `msgget` ?

Thanks.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a great resource for Android internals questions like these. StackOverflow is mostly used for questions related to building apps using the SDK. If you do not get an answer here, head over to http://source.android.com, choose an appropriate Google Group, and try asking there.

Comment: Most Linux systems (and Android is a Linux system at heart) can catch syscalls with `ptrace`. Did you investigate that route?

Comment: That would be what strace is doing.  But it's possible the strace binary used has a bad table of syscall numbers (built for a different version).

Comment: msgget() and msgrecv() are System V IPC functions, and Android does not support System V IPC as the designers felt it had problems including denial of service potential. This strongly suggests that the strace you used does not have quite the right syscall table, however what strace is doing with ptraces is a good approach, so you might look into rebuilding it, or just grepping the output for functions of interest (hopefully ones that are correct in its table)

Comment: Thanks for Googlegroup and ptrace suggestions and msgget() details. I was already in doubt with the output of strace.

Comment: Hi Junaid, Iam tracking down the same thing to trace all system calls the appication makes.I saw one google groups post from which I understand that you succeeded in implementing that. Could you please guide best way to do that (links or some other materials that pointing to how to do that). Thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This link](http://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/) mentions almost all the system calls, their arguments and locations in respective files. It helped me finding system call details.

and answer for strace is given in above comments by Chris, thanks to him again.

Comment: Obsolete link :( hence requirement to put answers here not links.

Comment: *32 bit*: http://eds000n.github.io/syscalls-x86.html
*64 bit*: http://eds000n.github.io/syscalls-x86_64.html